Cannot obtain IPv6 from stateful KEA DHCPv6 server
I am trying a little network setup at home (just for learning for now). DHVPv4 with KEA is working fine, but I am a bit confused with getting KEA-DHCPv6 to work (using ULA for internal DHCPv6 stateful testing and educational purposes).

Virtual Machine 'VM HomeServer' (Debian 12):
1.1 IP Address:
enp7s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 52:54:00:26:30:9f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.3/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp7s0
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 192.168.31.130/24 brd 192.168.31.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp7s0
valid_lft 41268sec preferred_lft 35868sec
inet6 fd00:0:0:1::3/64 scope global
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::85f4:b665:fd85:3d1e/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe26:309f/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever



This VM should act as stateful DHCPv6 router for the private network (in particular for ‘VM Sandbox’). I am using KEA as DHCPv6 application.

1.2 KEA DHCPv6 configuration:
{
  "Dhcp6": {
    "interfaces-config": {
      "interfaces": [
        "enp7s0"
      ]
    },
    "lease-database": {
      "type": "memfile",
      "persist": true,
      "name": "/var/lib/kea/kea-leases6.csv"
    },
    "valid-lifetime": 28800,
    "option-data": [
      {
        "name": "dns-servers",
        "data": "2001:4860:4860::8888, 2001:4860:4860::8844"
      }
    ],
    "subnet6": [
      {
        "subnet": "fd00:0000:0000:0001::/64",
        "pools": [
          {
            "pool": "fd00:0000:0000:0001::a - fd00:0000:0000:0001::ffff"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "loggers": [
      {
        "name": "kea-dhcp6",
        "severity": "DEBUG",
        "output_options": [
          {
            "output": "/var/log/kea/kea-dhcp6.log",
            "maxver": 10
          }
        ]
      },
            {
        "name": "kea-dhcp6.dhcpsrv",
        "severity": "DEBUG",
        "output_options": [
          {
            "output": "/var/log/kea/dhcp6-dhcpsrv.log",
            "maxver": 10
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "kea-dhcp6.leases",
        "severity": "DEBUG",
        "output_options": [
          {
            "output": "/var/log/kea/dhcp4-leases.log",
            "maxver": 10
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

1.3 RADVD:
interface enp7s0
{
MinRtrAdvInterval 3;
MaxRtrAdvInterval 4;
AdvSendAdvert on;
AdvManagedFlag on;
prefix fd00:0000:0000:0001::/64
{ AdvValidLifetime 14300; AdvPreferredLifetime 14200; AdvAutonomous off; }
;
};

1.4 UFW: active
1.5 VM network adapter is set as bridged on host.
1.6 Status KEA DHCPv6
1.6.1 From ‘/var/log/kea/kea-dhcp6.log’
2024-11-24 09:28:11.052 INFO  [kea-dhcp6.hosts/946.139846052082176] HOSTS_BACKENDS_REGISTERED the following host backend types are available: mysql postgresql 
2024-11-24 09:28:11.054 INFO  [kea-dhcp6.dhcp6/946.139846052082176] DHCP6_CONFIG_COMPLETE DHCPv6 server has completed configuration: added IPv6 subnets: 1; DDNS: disabled
2024-11-24 09:28:11.057 INFO  [kea-dhcp6.dhcp6/946.139846052082176] DHCP6_USING_SERVERID server is using server-id 00:01:00:01:2e:66:39:5e:52:54:00:41:2f:9d and stores in the file /var/lib/kea/kea-dhcp6-serverid
2024-11-24 09:28:11.058 WARN  [kea-dhcp6.dhcp6/946.139846052082176] DHCP6_MULTI_THREADING_INFO enabled: no, number of threads: 0, queue size: 0
2024-11-24 09:28:11.058 INFO  [kea-dhcp6.dhcp6/946.139846052082176] DHCP6_STARTED Kea DHCPv6 server version 2.2.0 started

1.6.2 From ‘systemctl status kea-dhcp6-server’
 kea-dhcp6-server.service - Kea IPv6 DHCP daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/kea-dhcp6-server.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-11-24 09:28:10 AEDT; 35min ago
       Docs: man:kea-dhcp6(8)
   Main PID: 946 (kea-dhcp6)
      Tasks: 5 (limit: 9449)
     Memory: 11.6M
        CPU: 344ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/kea-dhcp6-server.service

1.7 Status RADVD
1.7.1 From ‘systemctl status radvd.service’:
radvd.service - Router advertisement daemon for IPv6
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/radvd.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-11-24 09:45:22 AEDT; 19min ago
       Docs: man:radvd(8)
    Process: 2069 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/radvd --logmethod stderr_clean --configtest (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 2070 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/radvd --logmethod stderr_clean (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 2071 (radvd)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 9449)
     Memory: 464.0K
        CPU: 327ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/radvd.service

1.7.2 From ‘rdisc6 enp7s0’:
Soliciting ff02::2 (ff02::2) on enp7s0...
Hop limit                 :           64 (      0x40)
Stateful address conf.    :          Yes
Stateful other conf.      :           No
Mobile home agent         :           No
Router preference         :       medium
Neighbor discovery proxy  :           No
Router lifetime           :           12 (0x0000000c) seconds
Reachable time            :  unspecified (0x00000000)
Retransmit time           :  unspecified (0x00000000)
 Prefix                   : fd00:0:0:1::/64
  On-link                 :          Yes
  Autonomous address conf.:           No
  Valid time              :        14300 (0x000037dc) seconds
  Pref. time              :        14200 (0x00003778) seconds
 Source link-layer address: 52:54:00:26:30:9F
 from fe80::85f4:b665:fd85:3d1e

Hop limit                 :           64 (      0x40)
Stateful address conf.    :          Yes
Stateful other conf.      :           No
Mobile home agent         :           No
Router preference         :       medium
Neighbor discovery proxy  :           No
Router lifetime           :           12 (0x0000000c) seconds
Reachable time            :  unspecified (0x00000000)
Retransmit time           :  unspecified (0x00000000)
 Prefix                   : fd00:0:0:1::/64
  On-link                 :          Yes
  Autonomous address conf.:           No
  Valid time              :        14300 (0x000037dc) seconds
  Pref. time              :        14200 (0x00003778) seconds
 Source link-layer address: 52:54:00:26:30:9F
 from fe80::85f4:b665:fd85:3d1e


Virtual Machine 'VM Sandbox' (Debian 12)
2.1 IP Address:
enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 52:54:00:9b:35:94 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe9b:3594/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


2.2 Netplan:
network:
ethernets:
enp1s0:
dhcp4: yes
dhcp6: yes
optional: false
version: 2
renderer: networkd

2.3 UFW: active
2.4 VM network adapter is set as bridged on host.
2.5 Status RADVD
2.5.1 From ‘rdisc6 enp1s0’:
Soliciting ff02::2 (ff02::2) on enp1s0...
Hop limit                 :           64 (      0x40)
Stateful address conf.    :          Yes
Stateful other conf.      :           No
Mobile home agent         :           No
Router preference         :       medium
Neighbor discovery proxy  :           No
Router lifetime           :           12 (0x0000000c) seconds
Reachable time            :  unspecified (0x00000000)
Retransmit time           :  unspecified (0x00000000)
 Prefix                   : fd00:0:0:1::/64
  On-link                 :          Yes
  Autonomous address conf.:           No
  Valid time              :        14300 (0x000037dc) seconds
  Pref. time              :        14200 (0x00003778) seconds
 Source link-layer address: 52:54:00:26:30:9F
 from fe80::85f4:b665:fd85:3d1e

Hop limit                 :           64 (      0x40)
Stateful address conf.    :          Yes
Stateful other conf.      :           No
Mobile home agent         :           No
Router preference         :       medium
Neighbor discovery proxy  :           No
Router lifetime           :           12 (0x0000000c) seconds
Reachable time            :  unspecified (0x00000000)
Retransmit time           :  unspecified (0x00000000)
 Prefix                   : fd00:0:0:1::/64
  On-link                 :          Yes
  Autonomous address conf.:           No
  Valid time              :        14300 (0x000037dc) seconds
  Pref. time              :        14200 (0x00003778) seconds
 Source link-layer address: 52:54:00:26:30:9F
 from fe80::85f4:b665:fd85:3d1e


Additional observations:
3.1 RADVD:
If I change the RADVD configuration on ‘VM HomeServer’ to switch off AdvAutonomous (autonomous address configuration), the client ‘VM Sandbox’ sets it IPv6 IP based on the defined prefix (but obviosuly autonomously, so the DHCPv6 server on ‘VM HomeServer’ does not have an entry in its lease database in ‘/var/lib/kea/kea-leases6.csv’).

3.2 KEA:
This is the KEA server log:
2024-11-25 15:32:13.867 DEBUG [kea-dhcp6.packets/8707.
2024-11-25 15:32:13.867 DEBUG [kea-dhcp6.dhcp6/8707.
2024-11-25 15:32:13.867 DEBUG [kea-dhcp6.options/8707.
2024-11-25 15:32:13.867 DEBUG [kea-dhcp6.packets/8707.
2024-11-25 15:32:13.867 DEBUG [kea-dhcp6.packets/8707.
msgtype=2(ADVERTISE), transid=0x70f6ae
type=00001, len=00018: 00:04:8a:24:56:28:14:87:48:b1:
type=00002, len=00014: 00:01:00:01:2e:66:39:5e:52:54:
type=00003(IA_NA), len=00064: iaid=10171796, t1=0, t2=0,
options:
  type=00013, len=00048: NoAddrsAvail(2) "Server could not select subnet for this client"
type=00023, len=00032: 2001:4860:4860::8888 2001:4860:4860::8844
No relays traversed.


Questions:
What configuration do I miss to enable stateful DHCPv6 as I can’t figure out why KEA cannot determine a subnet for this request as indicated in the KEA server log?

Thank you so much.
Best,
C.

I found the root cause and the solution.
In the KEA configuration file (e.g. '/etc/kea/kea-dhcp6.conf'), you need to mention the interface in the subnet as well. Based on the configuration above, the KEA-config file shoule look like this on 'VM HomeServer':
{
  "Dhcp6": {
    "interfaces-config": {
      "interfaces": [
        "enp7s0"
      ]
    },
    "lease-database": {
      "type": "memfile",
      "persist": true,
      "name": "/var/lib/kea/kea-leases6.csv"
    },
    "valid-lifetime": 28800,
//    "option-data": [
//      {
//        "name": "dns-servers",
//        "data": "2001:4860:4860::8888, 2001:4860:4860::8844"
//      }
//    ],
    "subnet6": [
      {
        "subnet": "fd00:0:0:1::/48",
        "interface": "enp7s0",
        "pools": [
          {
            "pool": "fd00:0000:0000:0001::a-fd00:0000:0000:0001::ffff"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "loggers": [
      {
        "name": "kea-dhcp6",
        "severity": "DEBUG",
        "debuglevel": 99,
        "output_options": [
          {
            "output": "/var/log/kea/kea-dhcp6.log",
            "maxver": 10
          }
        ]
      },
            {
        "name": "kea-dhcp6.dhcpsrv",
        "severity": "DEBUG",
        "debuglevel": 99,
        "output_options": [
          {
            "output": "/var/log/kea/dhcp6-dhcpsrv.log",
            "maxver": 10
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "kea-dhcp6.leases",
        "severity": "DEBUG",
        "debuglevel": 99,
        "output_options": [
          {
            "output": "/var/log/kea/dhcp4-leases.log",
            "maxver": 10
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

The problem was also discussed here:
https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/kea-users/2017-June/001014.html
